# Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded

Tags: recursion

I'm not sure why this code is giving the error :(

```
f[0] = 0; 
f[n_] := f[n] = DigitCount[n, 10, 1] + f[n - 1];
f[1016]
```

[image]

Comment: It's not.  You probably have leftover definitions.  `ClearAll[f]` then try again.

Comment: still same error :(

Comment: What precise version of Mathematica are you using?  Have you tried restarting Mathematica?  If all this doesn't help, please restart Mathematica, try it again in a new notebook, and make a screenshot of the notebook (with code and error), then post it.

Comment: picture posted.

Comment: This code was not run immediately after restarting Mathematica so we have no way of knowing what may have been evaluated before. Do not rely on clearing the Global context, please restart Mathematica fully, make sure there's only a single notebook open, and do this again.  It's clear that the factor causing the problem is something you do not expect, so don't make assumptions about what is a sufficient substitute for restarting.

Comment: Szabolcs is right. `f[1016]` is 326.

Comment: Another thing I just noticed is that your screenshot has `1050`, which is greater than `1024`, while in the code you *posted* there's `1016`.  It is true that `f[1050]` will cause Mathematica to exceed the recursion limit.  You can increase `$RecursionLimit` to solve this.  `f[1016]` should not trigger the error.

Comment: the screenshot has 1050 because after restarting Mathematica, it ran 1016 fine, so I increased it to see if it works for all number now, but it broke at 1050. Is this really the limit for it? I'm afraid to increase recursion limit because Mathematica regularly freezes my laptop, even when I use "MemoryConstrained[ , (1024^3)]"
I was hoping to be able to get to much higher numbers with that function...

Comment: @Solarmew `Block[{$RecursionLimit = 10^6}, f[5000]]` for example. You need to understand what "recursion limit" means - the default recursion limit is 1024 and if you truly understood the limit you would realize that you have to increase it if you want evaluate the function for higher numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just a suggestion. Try to use [tail recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37010/353410) to free the stack.

```
ClearAll[f,g];
g[n_] := g[n] = f[n, 0]
f[0, x_] := x;
f[n_, upto_] := f[n - 1, upto + DigitCount[n, 10, 1]]
g[2000]
(*1600*)
```

Comment: You may reach $IterationLimit at some point, but you can set it larger with no impact at all