# Is there a difference between these two ways to define a function?

Tags: syntax, variable-definitions

(I took this example from [another question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/76268/recursion-depth-of-1024-exceeded))

```
f[0] = 0;
f[n_] := f[n] = DigitCount[n, 10, 1] + f[n - 1];
f[1016]
```

I notice that this example defines f(n) in a different way from the one given by [the documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DefiningFunctions.html), which would be (the second line changes):

```
f[0] = 0;
f[n_] := DigitCount[n, 10, 1] + f[n - 1];
f[1016]
```

Is there a difference between these two ways of defining the function? When I run it, the output is the same, implying there's no difference; however I'd like to be sure.

Comment: The first one has memory, the second one doesn’t. So when you use the first definition and do f[3] it does the math and *also stores the value*. The next time you call it, it just pulls the precomputed value. Trades storage for speed. A slick trick!

Comment: @MikeY suggest writing that as an answer :)

Comment: Nevermind: [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2639/what-does-the-construct-fx-fx-mean/) is a better one.